# Running phantomjs using Selenium WebDriver and java in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, webdriver, phantomjs

I've been trying to set up my machine to run phantomjs with Selenium WebDriver and java from Eclipse.  I've been able to run phantomjs from the commandline(installed globally with npm), so I'm pretty sure I'm just not setting it up correctly through Eclipse.

Here is a snippet of how I'm calling phantomjs in my test code:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

  dCaps = new DesiredCapabilities();
  dCaps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
  dCaps.setCapability("takesScreenshot", false);
  dCaps.setCapability("phantomjs.binary.path", "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs");

  driver = new PhantomJSDriver(dCaps);
  baseUrl = "http://assertselenium.com/";
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Before I run the test from Eclipse, do I need to manually start phantomjs or the selenium server?

Are there certain files that should be included in the bootstrap classpath?

Comment: What error/exception are you getting?

Comment: Eclipse log: org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService <init> INFO: executable: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs Jun 23, 2014 10:02:01 AM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService <init> INFO: port: 17255 Jun 23, 2014 10:02:01 AM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService <init> INFO: arguments: [--webdriver=17255, --webdriver-logfile=/Users/drewdimanlig/Documents/workspace/spark/phantomjsdrive‌​r.log] Jun 23, 2014 10:02:01 AM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService <init> INFO: environment: {} env: node: No such file or directory

Comment: This from the eclipse failure trace:  org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.

Comment: although it is too late, here are the solution: sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/node /usr/bin/node